# Catch all route interfering with static files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to route all unmapped URLs into a fallback route which I will have control of the behavior of the request if the route is unmapped. Below is the code that enables this. This site is also SPA enabled and by adding the fall back catch all route, the SPA stops working unless I add an exclusion constraint by saying that any routes that don't end with '-ng' will not be routed to this fallback.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action ="Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "fallback",
        template: "{*slug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Fallback", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new
        {
            serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url => !url.PathAndQuery.EndsWith("-ng", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        }
    );
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

The exclusion constraint seems to have done its job but now it looks like I have to add exclusion constraint to static files as well. I want to avoid excluding by file extensions, but this has me thinking that my UseSpaStaticFiles call is just being overridden by my fallback route.

What would help is if there's a way to have the SPA routes take precedence over my fallback. Or have a way to route all the static files by local directory prior to hitting the fallback.

Comment: As long as your static files exist, `UseStaticFiles` ought to notice them and serve them before MVC middleware takes over the request.

Comment: Thanks, this help, perhaps my files are just in the wrong location. I'll look into this and update my question as needed.

Comment: Yes. Since the static files middleware is declared before your the MVC middleware (which includes your routing), then any URLs that exist as static files will be served as those static files *first*, and then will fall into the MVC middleware pipeline otherwise. The only thing that would explain things getting caught by your catch all route is if they literally don't exist as static files.

Comment: I have the reverse problem - static files stop getting served if there is a controller catch all route defined. Very odd...